# Type 'Any' Has no Subscript Members in Xcode 8.1 Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I am following [This Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XIQsQ2injLo)
and I am facing the issue **Type 'Any' Has no Subscript Members**   when I defined the title and message in the ViewController.Swiftm I am waiting for your kind suggestions

[image]
here is the code:
**View Controller:**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

struct postStruct {
let title : String
let message : String
}


class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

let posts = [postStruct]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    databaseRef.child("posts").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

    let title = snapshot.value!["title"] as! String
    let message = snapshot.value!["message"] as! String

        self.posts.insert(contentsOf: postStruct(title: title , message: message), at: index, 0)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })

    post()

}

func post () {
    let title = "Title"
    let message = "Message"
    let post:[String:AnyObject] = ["title":title as AnyObject,"message":message as AnyObject]

    let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    databaseRef.child("posts").childByAutoId().setValue(post)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return posts.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")

    let label1 = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
    label1.text = posts[indexPath.row].title

    let label2 = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
    label2.text = posts[indexPath.row].message


}

}
```

Comment: Looks like you missed the dozens of similar questions and their existing answers when you did research about this issue... *cough*

Comment: @EricAya i have read dozen of questions first.

Comment: @EricAya they are somewhat different.

Comment: They're all the same, really: "the compiler doesn't know what is the real type of your value behind Any, you have to cast to the right type before using subscript". The end.

Comment: Ok dear I am trying my best

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast `snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]` first because the compiler does not know what type of snapshot.value is.

Like this:

```
    if let value = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {

        let title = value["title"] as! String
        let message = value["message"] as! String
        self.posts.insert(contentsOf: postStruct(title: title, message: message), at: index, 0)
        self.tableView.reloadData()    
    }
```

Comment: thanks akash where should i place this and what shoul i remove?

Comment: @JackDowson From "let title" to above "post()"